# How to get all the links (Titles and Sub links) using selenium

Tags: css, arrays, selenium, xpath

Actually I am checking the excel values whether they are displayed on the web page Mouse hover menu. The menu includes titles and the menu item links. The menu items in main menu and the sub links are in child menu. When I tried to collect all the links, I am getting them separately by finding with CSS. I want to get all the links in one array. I have used the below commands. Please help me how to get all the elements in one array. The developers code is attached as screen shots :

[image: hovermenu]

[image: hovermenucodefortitle]

[image: hovermenucodefortitle]

```
String AdminRoleAccessfilepath = "D:\\PMC  
Automation\\AdminRoleAccess.xls";
FileInputStream AdminRoleFile=new 
FileInputStream(AdminRoleAccessfilepath);
Workbook rwb=Workbook.getWorkbook(AdminRoleFile);
Sheet AdminRolesheet=rwb.getSheet("AdminRole");
int submenucolumnsize=AdminRolesheet.getRows();
int menucolumnsize=AdminRolesheet.getRows();
String[] arraysubmenu=new String[submenucolumnsize];
String[] arraymenu=new String[menucolumnsize];

List<WebElement>SubTitlelist = 
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".child_menu>a "));
List<String> allSubTitleslist=new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement>Titleslist = 
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#menu_nav>ul>li>a "));

int submenuui = 0;
for (int a=1;a<submenucolumnsize;a++)
{
    arraysubmenu[a] = AdminRolesheet.getCell(1,a).getContents();
    //System.out.println(arraymenu[a]);

        boolean isthere = true;

        for(submenuui=0; submenuui<SubTitlelist.size(); submenuui++)
        {
        if 
(!(arraysubmenu[a]).equalsIgnoreCase
(SubTitlelist.get(submenuui).getText()))
        {
            isthere = false;
      }
        else
        {
            isthere = true;
            break;
        }
      }
if(isthere)
        System.out.println("\nThe Sub Menu item in the UI-> " 
+arraysubmenu[a]+ " existing on the Web Page" );
    else
        System.out.println("\nThe Sub Menu item in the UI-> " 
+arraysubmenu[a]+ " not existing on the Web Page");
}

int menuui = 0;
    for (int b=1;b<menucolumnsize;b++)
    {
        arraymenu[b] = AdminRolesheet.getCell(1,b).getContents();
        //System.out.println(arraymenu[a]);
            boolean isthere = true;

            for(menuui=0; menuui<Titleslist.size(); menuui++)
            {   
            if (!(arraymenu[b]).equalsIgnoreCase
 (Titleslist.get(menuui).getText()))
            {
                isthere = false;
             }
            else
            {
                isthere = true;
                break;
            }
           }
 if(isthere)
            System.out.println("\nThe Title in the Menu in the UI-> " 
 +arraymenu[b]+ " existing on the Web Page" );
        else
            System.out.println("\nThe Title in the Menu in the UI-> " 
 +arraymenu[b]+ " not existing on the Web Page");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the selectors into one CSS using a comma.

```
'.child_menu>a , #menu_nav>ul>li>a'
```

Comment: @SuneelKuppili http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work